# How to do IP walk in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, networking, network-programming

my computer's IP is 192.168.1.101 over eth0.
I want to know what are other active/used IP under 192.168.1.*
I am expecting a list of IP address that is ping-able under 192.168.1.*
How can I do that in C? And preferably in linux platform.
Any C functions available?

Comment: Are you allowed to ping the broadcast address on your network?

Comment: Used IP addresses may not necessarily be pingable.  Per-machine firewalls can block pings easily.  You might get better answers if you clarify *for what purpose* you want this information.

Comment: http://nmap.org/ <- does that in C.

Comment: Try this: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: @cdhowie - if i cannot ping (because of different reasons like firewall), then my C should skip that address.

Comment: @Neilvert: Then how about pinging each address and seeing which ones respond?

Comment: I'm just curious how to do that in C. If there's existing function for it, etc... Thanks for the comment:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function in C that sends ping packet. There is, however, function that just sends packet. There is also a lot of code in the internet that already implements ping.

What you have to do is just take one of them ([this](http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/source/utils/sh/ping.c.html) for example) and ping in a loop for all addresses in your network.

You should know, however, that ping is not a reliable way of saying which addresses are in use. RFC 792 - Internet Control Message Protocol says:

> The Internet Protocol is not designed
>   to be absolutely reliable. The purpose
>   of these control messages is to
>   provide feedback about problems in the
>   communication environment, not to make
>   IP reliable. There are still no guarantees that a datagram will be
>   delivered or a    control message will
>   be returned.  Some datagrams may still
>   be    undelivered without any report
>   of their loss.

which means that any message can be easily lost, with no notification. Furthermore, target does not have to respond.